# How to select element by inner text using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to use puppeteer to select a checkbox based on the text within two  tags.

I am trying to automate a wordpress plugin, this is the html for the element I need to select:

```
<li id="at_biz_dir-location-5" class="popular-category">
    <label class="selectit">. 
        <input value="5" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[at_biz_dir-location][]" id="in-at_biz_dir-location-5"> Melborn</label> 
</li>
```

so in this case I'd like to select this element by using the string "Melbourn", which I will receive in a post request to this script.

I understand that it's easier for me to append the id (5) from `id="in-at_biz_dir-location-5` but it's not possible in this situation to recieve the id.

Comment: puppeteer != puppet.  Tags updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`page.$$eval()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args):

```js
await page.$$eval(
    'label > input',
    inputs => inputs.filter(input => input.innerText === 'Melbourn')
);
```

Comment: When I run console.log(that function) I just get an empty arrray, any idea why?

Comment: Try to experiment with it a little bit, it's hard to say when I don't have access to the site. What comes to mind is " Melborn" vs. "Melborn", you have an extra space there, maybe it's like this in the DOM. Try to use browser dev tools first to get to the elements and filter it down to what you need.

Comment: @JonathanZier You get an empty array because $$eval() returns only a Serializable, and thus, since you are trying to return an HTMLElement, (which is non-serializable), you get undefined instead.